# SerialPort COM Port over RDP

Tags: c#, serial-port

I try to connect to an USB device which is accessible on Virtual COM Port X.
Everything works fine (local). Now I'm using a RDP (remote desktop) session and try to connect to my device I don't get any response.
RDP COM Port redirecting is activated. If I run:

```
SerialPort.GetPortNames()
```

on my RDP Session I will get the right port (in my case COM Port 9). 
Then i try to connect:

```
_port.Open();
_port.Write(buffer, offset, count);
```

I can see that my device (connected on my none RDP Session host) retreive some bytes (LED are blinking) but I never get any response/results.

If I try it local, everything works fine.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, not much to go on.  Can you provide a code example?

Comment: There is no more code. The problem is to retreive data. I think the device is retreive the right data and send other data back, but the application doesn't get the result (the problem occurs only on the rdp session).

Comment: One practice I follow is to capture and check the returned values of the read and write function (especially when related to network).

Comment: Have you configured *ALL* properties of the [`SerialPort` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) (BaudRate, Databits, etc.)?

Comment: Yes I've tried it with all properties. But it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Can you confirm if you are connecting to the device on the target PC not from the PC you are opening the remote desktop from?

Local Setup:
Target_PC -> USB_Device = Works

Remote Setup:
Other_PC -RDP-> Target_PC -> USB_Device = Should work